# SQL alchemy prefixes table name to columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using delcarative base in sql-alchemy to query data:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
OdsBase = declarative_base(metadata=sql.MetaData(schema='ods'))

class BagImport(OdsBase):
    __tablename__ = 'bag_stg_import' 
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True} 
    PAN = sql.Column(sql.String(50), primary_key = True)
    GEM = sql.Column(sql.String(50))
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<{0} Pan: {1} - Gem: {2}>".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.PAN, self.GEM)
```

If I do, I get a proper result:

```
my_session.query(BagImport).first()
```

But if I want to see the query and I do:

```
the_query = my_session.query(BagImport)
print(the_query)
```

I get the output query as:

```
SELECT ods.bag_stg_import."PAN" AS "ods_bag_stg_import_PAN_1", ods.bag_stg_import."GEM" AS "ods_bag_stg_import_GEM_2"
FROM ods.bag_stg_import
```

Why is SQL-Alchemy prefixing the table name in the alias e.g. `SELECT ods.bag_stg_import."PAN" AS "ods_bag_stg_import_PAN_1"`?

How can I make it AS `SELECT ods.bag_stg_import."PAN" AS "PAN"`?

Comment: It does this to ensure uniqueness of column names in the query.  Judging from the warning in [Query.with_labels](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_labels) this behaviour can't be disabled, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Though if you just want to print the query without the labels, `the_query.statement` might work.

Comment: ```print(the_query.statement)```, works!

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a way to do this. In my case, I was having issues with `except_`, which prefixes columns with the table name. Here's how I did that:

```
def _except(included_query, excluded_query, Model, prefix):
    """An SQLALchemy except_ that removes the prefixes on the columns, so they can be
    referenced in a subquery by their un-prefixed names."""
    query = included_query.except_(excluded_query)
    subquery = query.subquery()
    # Get a list of columns from the subquery, relabeled with the simple column name.
    columns = []
    for column_name in _attribute_names(Model):
        column = getattr(subquery.c, prefix + column_name)
        columns.append(column.label(column_name))
    # Wrap the query to select the simple column names. This is necessary because
    # except_ prefixes column names with a string derived from the table name.
    return Model.query.from_statement(Model.query.with_entities(*columns).statement)
```

**Old answer:**

This happened to me when using the `except_` query method like this:

```
included_query.except_(excluded_query)
```

I fixed it by changing to this pattern

```
excluded_subquery = excluded_query.with_entities(ModelClass.id).subquery()
included_query.filter(ModelClass.id.notin_(excluded_subquery))
```

Comment: FYI we decided not to go this route because of performance concerns of using `notin_` vs `except_`. So we just have to live with this column name weirdness...

Answer (score -4):

just mention below meta property in your model

```
__tablename__ = 'Users'
```

them sqlaclchemy will take the  proper table name

Comment: why Users? I have the correct table name already: ```__tablename__ = 'bag_stg_import'```

Comment: i have given example